# Grails upgrade from 1.2.2 to version that supports multiple datasources

Tags: grails

I have several applications created with grails 1.2.2. I need to modify one of these applications to work with multiple datasources. It seems that my best option is to upgrade to a new version of grails. I'm worried that trying to go straight to grails 3 will cause major issues, but am not sure which versions to step through if I'm going to upgrade gradually. Any advice? I apologize for this being so open ended.

Answer (score 0):

The first info about support for multiple databases in official docs exists in version 2.0.0:
http://docs.grails.org/2.0.0/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Check out this guide for upgrade:
http://docs.grails.org/2.0.0/guide/gettingStarted.html#upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails